# How to resolve AWS resources dynamically at runtime?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cdk

Until now I stored ARNs for different environments in config files, now I want to resolve the ARNs dynamically at runtime, but I'm not able to find any "best practices" for this.

The resources are managed with AWS CDK so I have multiple options to store/retrieve the ARNs at runtime:

- create and query Parameter Store entries
- create and query Stack outputs for each resource
- query the resources of the Stack
- query the resources by using the SDK for specific services

What would you recommend?

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: store the arns as env vars or other configuration. then load that at starup

Comment: Why do you want to change your current config-based approach? What problem is that currently causing or, alternatively, what benefits are you hoping to achieve from a dynamic approach?

Comment: I'm currently creating a new application and I don't want to "hard code" ARNs for multiple environments (currently development, staging and production) anymore.

Comment: Any thoughts about the "why" questions @jarmod asked?  Need to know more about the problem before recommending a solution.  See the [CDK application best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps) for some general considerations.

Comment: @fedonev The main reason is that I want to be able to spin up any number of environments without creating config files for every environment. In addition I want to try out Spring AOT-compilation and that does not work well with profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Since my application needs access to the parameter store anyway, I decided to store the ARNs there.